# Adding a syntax for extending php rather than a library with php-cpp

Tags: php, php-cpp

I was interested in adding some feature to the php syntax, and definitly it's obvious for me it's different from writing modules for the language.
I was wondering this requires to edit the resource in C which is avaialble on the php.net website and naturally C programming knowledge.
Simply I want do the below:

```
xforeach ($array as $item with $counter) {
    echo "This is $counter time this loop is happening";
}
```

Rather than writing:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo "This is $counter time this loop is happening";
    $counter ++;
}
```

or in another glimpse, adding attribute to each class or function, like it's possible in C#

```
class MyClass {

    [Description("This is my php 6 version")]
    public function Test() {


    }
}
```

What is the first step on the way to achieving this approach?

Comment: So a .NET PHP implementation? That already exists and is called Phalanger.

Comment: There are several implementations of Linq for PHP

Comment: If you want to work with changes to the actual syntax of PHP, I suggest you start following the PHP internals mailing list

Comment: Note that MVC6 (on vNext) will also be able to run on Linux an Mac envrinments http://www.asp.net/vnext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how other people did it: http://hacklang.org/ (from facebook)

They build their own language on php (which compiles to php in the end)

What you do is:

1. you define your own file extension
2. str_replace your own code with php code <= this will be your compiler.
3. run your created php code.

Note: this is also how template engines work, like Twig.

## discouragement

In the end you either write php or you write C#.

- Php doesnt need generics because it is not typechecked!

Note: Even if you would succeed their would not be an IDE with IntelliSense to write your code in.

why would you want to make php like C#, why not just code in C#?

Note: vNext (MVC6) will be able to run on Linux servers as well, with the new Roslyn compiler.

Comment: Is it possible to add a keyword to php? so, how the Zend company does it?

Comment: VS PHP can intellisence the code in future?

Comment: new kewords to php comes from at least two ways: source code of PHP, and extensions (DLLs in windows case)

Comment: A compiler does *not* work by simply `str_replacing` strings. That'd be an extremely primitive and limited compiler.

Comment: Yes, thats why its debatable if you can call it compiler, but it compiles to PHP code. and yes i would use regexes, but in the end it is just a search and replace (maybe setup in an OO environment).